# Sets, Set Notation and Equations Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C \subseteq Z^2 $ where $ Z = \{(x,y) \mid y = 2x+1 \}, B = \{(x,y) \mid y = 3x\}$, and 
$C = \{ (x,y)\mid x-y=7\}$. Determine a) $A \cap B$ b) $B \cap C$.

I've tried plugging in $x$ values into each equation provided. 
i.e. $B(x) = 3x$ so $B(1) = 3$. Not really sure what do after that though.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a definition of $A\cap B$ for these particular sets? If you can, it should give you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: I that $\mathbb Z$ for $Z$ and $A=\{(x,y)|y=2x+1\}$?

Comment: Well Integers for Z yes, however this was the exact question posed in my homework.  Maybe prof mistyped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $A$, not $Z$, is equal to the set $\{(x, y) : y = 2x+1\}$, then $A\cap B$ is the set of all pairs $(x, y)$ common to both $A$ and $B$.  If $(x, y)$ is in $A$, then $y = 2x + 1$; if $(x, y)$ is in $B$, then $y = 3x$.  So if $(x, y)$ is in both $A$ and $B$, then $3x = y = 2x + 1$ implies $x = 1$.  Thus, $A\cap B$ is the singleton $\{(1, 3)\}$.

By the same reasoning, if $(x, y) \in B \cap C$ then $x = -7/2$; does your set $Z$ contain $x$?